# Very Low Mic sound problem in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Lenovo G50-70)

Tags: sound, lenovo, microphone

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04. Everything is working fine except sound.

- Mic is not properly working. Particularly on Skype calls, the other person is hardly able to hear my voice despite speaking very loudly.

I followed this link: [Ubuntu on Lenovo G50-70/G40-70](https://askubuntu.com/questions/489851/ubuntu-on-lenovo-g50-70-g40-70)

And installed **Cinnamon** but don't know how to install drivers or enable the sound in Ubuntu.

Much appreciate your response.

Answer (score 1):

First off, use the speaker button on the top right corner of your home screen. When you click that, you will be able to see various audio profiles. Also you can control the audio level of various applications from the same. 
If you are using lubuntu, you might get Audio Mixer. To get to this go to Home> Sound and Video> Audio Mixer. Check if the audio level is low there.

If all else fails, install alsamixer. You can use Synaptic Package manager for this. Alsamixer has a huge number of options to help you control the audio levels from different audio sources.

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: Hi Anushka, Thanks for speedy reply.

I have a alsamixer installed and I turned all volume up, mic boos>up but did not work out. I don't know what is the issue.

Comment: In Alsamixer, you have to press F4 function key to access recording settings  (you may also have to press F6 to select the main soundcard , modern pc have often 2 soundcards)